# Read an SQLite 2 database using Python 3

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

I have an old SQLite 2 database that I would like to read using Python 3 (on Windows). Unfortunately, it seems that Python's sqlite3 library does not support SQLite 2 databases. Is there any other convenient way to read this type of database in Python 3? Should I perhaps compile an older version of pysqlite? Will such a version be compatible with Python 3?

Comment: If you just need a quick solution: Export it in sqlite2 (dump) and import it into sqlite3, you can use python then.

Comment: I actually need a solution that works directly on the old SQLite 2 database without a conversion to SQLite 3. Nevertheless thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the pysqlite author I am pretty sure nobody has ported pysqlite 1.x to Python 3 yet. The only solution that makes sense effort-wise is the one theomega suggested.

If all you need is access the data from Python for importing them elsewhere, but doing the sqlite2 dump/sqlite3 restore dance is not possible, there is an option, but it is not convenient: Use the builtin ctypes module to access the necessary functions from the SQLite 2 DLL. You would then implement a minimal version of pysqlite yourself that only wraps what you really need.