# Python doesn't select joined Tables from SQlite database while just running a query works fine

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.6

I am using Python 3.6.3 and SQLite 3.14.2. I have two tables with one having a foreign key pointin to the other one. When I run the query with join in SQlite browser, it works fine and returns the results I need. But when I try to execute the query in Python, it always return empty list. No matter how simple I make the join, the result is same. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

```
    query = '''SELECT f.ID, f.FoodItemName, f.WaterPerKilo, r.AmountInKilo FROM 
            FoodItems AS f INNER JOIN RecipeItems AS r on f.ID=r.FoodItemID 
    WHERE r.RecipeID = {:d}'''.format(db_rec[0])
    print(query) 
    db_fooditems = cur.execute(query).fetchall() #this returns []
```

The Tables are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "FoodItems" (
`ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`FoodItemName`  TEXT NOT NULL,
`WaterPerKilo`  REAL NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE "RecipeItems" (
`ID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
`RecipeID`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
`FoodItemID`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
`AmountInKilo`  REAL NOT NULL)
```

with some random data.

Comment: Are you using an external sqlite module? I didn't think python could interact with SQLite2 databases.

Comment: I'm using sqlite3 module. I thouhgt SQlite was built in into Python.

Comment: SQLite3 is. I don't think SQLite2 is, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16193630/read-an-sqlite-2-database-using-python-3

Comment: Oh. Can you tell me how to install the SQLite 3 for python?

Comment: Are you sure you are actually opening the correct database file?

Comment: Yeah, it works when I select from single table.

Comment: Oh, apparently, I have SQlite version 3.14.2, not 2.6.0. 2.6.0 was the "Python ‘sqlite3’ database adapter module."

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes more sense. I don't see anything wrong with your query... if you could provide enough data to allow others to reproduce the result, we might be able to be more helpful.